# Use 2 different columns depending on a value within an Eloquent Model

Tags: php, eloquent

got a strange scenario here and going to try my best to explain it, i'm basically merging 2 separate systems which are very similar but use different column names.

So, **tablea** has got **one** **tableb**, however **tableb** is either selected using column `id_1` or `id_2`.

This check is done within a local scope when using the model directly:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tableb extends Model
{


    protected $table = 'tableb';       

    public function scopeMode(Builder $query, $id)
    {
        if (env('DEMO_MODE')) {
            return $query->where('id1', '=', $id);
        }
        return $query->where('id2', '=', $id);
    }


}
```

So to using the above model as follows works fine:

```
Tablea::mode()->first();
```

However, using this within a relationship then has issues, as the related column name can change, so I must do the same logic within this relationship, but I want to do all of this logic in one place (tableb) to avoid doing it in other relationships:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tablea extends Model
{

    public function Tableb()
    {
        if (env('DEMO_MODE')) {
            return $this->hasOne(Tableb::class, 'id2', 'tableb_id');
        }

        return $this->hasOne(Tableb::class, 'id1', 'tableb_id');
    }

}
```

Ideas?

Comment: One thing you can do in my opinion is having a static function in `table b` that returns which column you should use, something like `static function getId() { env('DEMO_MODE') ? 'id2' : 'id1' }` and then o `table a` instead of using a static string you could call this function.

Comment: That's a good idea @FranciscoSoares, fancy making that an answer?

Comment: Why not have a different demo DB with the demo data? Then all you have to do is swap your connection, not any of your logic. Works exactly the same as a dev & live environment would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An suggestion would be creating a static function on the `tableb` that returns which id should be used in `tablea`, something like the following:

(**NOTE**: I haven't tested the code yet)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tableb extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tableb';       

    public function scopeMode(Builder $query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where(self::getId(), '=', $id);
    }

    public static function getId()
    {
        return env('DEMO_MODE') ? 'id2' : 'id1';
    }
}
```

and then

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tablea extends Model
{
    public function Tableb()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Tableb::class, Tableb::getId(), 'tableb_id');
    }
}
```